# How to prevent others changing content of returned struct

Tags: go

In my program I have a cache to store some struct, and others can use the `Get` method to get according struct. How can I protect it from being changed by others if struct contains pointer(map)?

Background is my colleagues and I are working in same package, and when they use `get` function, I just return a copy of my struct, but this won't work if struct contains pointer. I know deep copy might be a solution, but if struct contains some big map, it will be painful to deep copy.

Example code is as follows:

```
// a.go
package foo

type bar struct {
    largeMap map[int]int
}
var cache map[int]bar
func getById(id int) bar {
    return cache[id]
}

// b.go
package foo
func fun() {
    p := getById(1)
    p.largeMap[2] = 34 // changing the original data in cache!!!!!
}
```

Comment: The only way to do this is to use a private struct field, and make all access go through getters and setters.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But as far as I know, in golang, you cannot prevent other access you `private` field if you are working in the same package. And for getters and setters, I still have to deep copy large map.

Comment: That's right. But "others" shouldn't be using the same package. The exact same situation exists in literally every other language with data protection. If you're inside the layer of protection, the protection doesn't apply.

Comment: The right answer is that it is impossible. If the user code is in the same package, it can directly access the `cache` map and shortcut the `getByID` function.

Answer (score 2):

> How to prevent others changing content of returned struct in [Go]

You cannot.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use a getter function.

We isolate all non pointer fields in a struct named `barPublic` for instance. The function `getByID` will return a copy of this struct. 
To access values from the map of `bar`, we then use the specialized getter function `getByIDAndKey`.

```golang
// struct containing non pointer fields of bar
type barPublic struct {
    x string
}

type bar struct {
    barPublic
    largeMap map[int]int
}

var cache map[int]bar

func getByID(id int) (barPublic, bool) {
    v, ok := cache[id]
    if !ok {
        return barPublic{}, false
    }
    return v.barPublic, true
}

func getByIDAndKey(id, key int) int {
    v, ok := cache[id]
    if !ok {
        return 0, false
    }
    w, ok := v.largeMap[key]
    if !ok {
        return 0, false
    }
    return w, true
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is absolutely a possible solution, but the drawback is that it's not extensible: if the struct contains many pointers or maps, it's not really likely to write all getters for these fields. However, I don't think there is other better solution for this...

Comment: @Cheng I don’t see any other way to prevent write access to pointer values. Beside, if the user code is in the same package, it’s totally impossible to prevent it to modify any variable in the package. The user could shortcut the getter function.